# Simple recursion function in python

Tags: python, function, recursion

Very new to coding and especially functions. I am trying to create a recursion function that starts at `n == 1`, divides `n` by two, and then continue to divide the next number by two. The math way is `fn = fn-1/2`. code is as follows

```
def half(n):
    return half(n/2)
half(1)
```

but i keep getting "maximum recursion depth exceeded"

help please?

Comment: Recursive functions need some sort of base case so you don't recursively call the function forever. When should this stop? The limit of continually diving by two is zero, but you will never get there (see [Zeno's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes)).

Comment: `half()` calls `half()` which calls `half()` and so on and on, forever.  You need a condition inside the code that returns an actual value instead of calling itself recursively again.

Comment: You maybe should design something like this on paper first, and think about it, before putting it into code; if you wrote this out on paper, it'd be obvious that it would never end. It's going to go like `half(1)`, `half(0.5)`, `half(0.25)`, `half(0.125)`, `half(0.0625)`, and so on, forever (well in theory, in practice it'll hit the max recursion depth). Why wouldn't it?

Comment: yes this makes sense. Instructions professor gave me did not warn that this would be a problem in python. I set a condition that stops it once n < .0001 and it works now. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a limit to recursion, you can’t display infinite
Something like when if n>0.00001: return half(n/2) else return n

Comment: the condition of making n>.0001 worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting a recursion limit in Python. Your function would lead to infinite recursion if Python didn't stop at the maximum recursion depth.

Comment: and infinite recursion would pretty much lead to crashing your computer because the cpu and ram usage would exceed all limits eventually (and pretty quickly too)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the function pretty much the same way as its mathematical formulation but you need some way to stop the recursion (i.e. a base case that doesn't need to recurse to get the answer).

for example, if the result for f(0) is known to be 1 then that's the base case where you can return the answer without calling the function again:

```
def f(n):
    if n==0: return 1         # base case f(0) --> 1 (stops recursion)
    else:    return f(n-1)/2  # recursion fn=fn-1/2

print(f(10)) # 0.0009765625   # this happens to be 1/2^10
```